# Directories in /usr/bin/ not openable. The directories seem to be replaced by "link" icons

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, bug-reporting

A link to a screenshot of what the directory looks like when opened in nautilius :

[image]

I even tried using the terminal to access these directories but to no avail.

Output of ls -l

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14704 Apr 10  2014 syndaemon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       51256 Jan 13  2014 syslinux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1421 Jan 13  2014 syslinux2ansi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       29768 Apr 16  2012 syslinux-legacy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root          95 Jan 30 00:46 system-config-printer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root          80 Jan 30 00:46 system-config-printer-applet
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35368 Oct 10  2013 t1ascii
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       40552 Oct 10  2013 t1asm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35336 Oct 10  2013 t1binary
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43552 Oct 10  2013 t1disasm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       47784 Oct 10  2013 t1mac
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43760 Oct 10  2013 t1unmac
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14680 Mar 23  2014 tabs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       31392 Jan 14 09:20 tac
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       64320 Jan 14 09:20 tail
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43472 Jan 23  2014 tangle
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         237 Jan  8  2014 tap2deb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         325 Jan  8  2014 tap2rpm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         219 Jan  8  2014 tapconvert
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18808 Feb 13 00:23 taskset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      109064 Jan 22  2014 tbl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Jun  3  2014 tclsh -> tclsh8.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        6168 Jan  3  2014 tclsh8.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Dec  6  2014 tdbbackup -> /etc/alternatives/tdbbackup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10440 Oct 21  2013 tdbbackup.tdbtools
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10352 Oct 21  2013 tdbdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10352 Oct 21  2013 tdbrestore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       19168 Oct 21  2013 tdbtool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1183992 Jan 23  2014 teckit_compile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       31328 Jan 14 09:20 tee
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       36024 Apr 11  2014 telepathy-indicator
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          24 Jun  3  2014 telnet -> /etc/alternatives/telnet
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       95424 Oct  3  2012 telnet.netkit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35456 Jan 14 09:20 test
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       23240 Feb 23 21:27 testparm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          11 Feb 15  2014 testrb -> testrb1.9.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         299 Nov 20  2014 testrb1.9.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      315616 Jan 23  2014 tex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          56 Feb 17  2014 texconfig -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/texconfig.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          63 Feb 17  2014 texconfig-dialog -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/texconfig-dialog.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          60 Feb 17  2014 texconfig-sys -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/texconfig-sys.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          56 Feb 20  2014 texcount -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texcount/texcount.pl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          52 Feb 20  2014 texdef -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texdef/texdef.pl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          51 Feb 20  2014 texdiff -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texdiff/texdiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          63 Feb 20  2014 texdirflatten -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texdirflatten/texdirflatten
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          53 Feb 17  2014 texdoc -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texdoc/texdoc.tlu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          56 Feb 17  2014 texdoctk -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texdoctk/texdoctk.pl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Jan 23  2014 texhash -> mktexlsr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          55 Feb 17  2014 texlinks -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/texlinks.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          64 Feb 20  2014 texliveonfly -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texliveonfly/texliveonfly.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          65 Feb 20  2014 texloganalyser -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texloganalyser/texloganalyser
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           6 Dec 14  2013 texlua -> luatex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           6 Dec 14  2013 texluac -> luatex
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35184 Jan 23  2014 tftopl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14440 Feb  7  2013 tgatoppm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        2295 Oct 10  2013 tgz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18648 Feb  7  2013 thinkjettopbm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         103 Jan 16  2014 thor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18936 Apr  2 00:38 thumbnail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          56 Feb 17  2014 thumbpdf -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/thumbpdf/thumbpdf.pl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          33 Mar 31 04:18 thunderbird -> ../lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       64288 Mar 23  2014 tic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       27216 Dec 15  2013 tidy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14504 Jan 23  2014 tie
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14792 Apr  2 00:38 tiff2bw
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       68464 Apr  2 00:38 tiff2pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       52720 Apr  2 00:38 tiff2ps
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14416 Apr  2 00:38 tiff2rgba
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18496 Apr  2 00:38 tiffcmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35592 Apr  2 00:38 tiffcp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      102704 Apr  2 00:38 tiffcrop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14528 Apr  2 00:38 tiffdither
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       22720 Apr  2 00:38 tiffdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18576 Apr  2 00:38 tiffinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18560 Apr  2 00:38 tiffmedian
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14408 Apr  2 00:38 tiffset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14336 Apr  2 00:38 tiffsplit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18600 Feb  7  2013 tifftopnm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        2972 Mar  4  2014 tilt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14880 Jun 29  2012 time
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       59480 Feb 20 03:01 timedatectl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       52496 Jan 14 09:20 timeout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          52 Feb 17  2014 tlmgr -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14720 Feb 11 01:38 tload
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        4400 May 31  2013 tl-paper
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Nov  7  2013 todos -> fromdos
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14704 Mar 23  2014 toe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      100776 Feb 11 01:38 top
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       95160 May 23  2012 toshset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18392 Apr  1  2014 totem
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18488 Apr  1  2014 totem-audio-preview
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       38992 Apr  1  2014 totem-video-thumbnailer
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Jan 14 09:20 touch -> /bin/touch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       12627 Jan 23  2014 tpic2pdftex
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14744 Mar 23  2014 tput
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43648 Jan 14 09:20 tr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14680 May  8  2014 tracepath
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14688 May  8  2014 tracepath6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          29 Jun  3  2014 traceroute6 -> /etc/alternatives/traceroute6
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root       23104 May  8  2014 traceroute6.iputils
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      808680 Jul 12  2014 transmission-gtk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       15736 Jan  6  2014 transset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         352 Jan  8  2014 trial
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      495544 Jan 22  2014 troff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       51912 Jan 14 09:20 truncate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      159104 Mar 20  2014 trust
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18976 Mar 23  2014 tset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35424 Jan 14 09:20 tsort
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35592 Mar 13  2014 tst_inactivity_timer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       33256 Jan 23  2014 ttf2afm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       68704 Jan 23  2014 ttf2pk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       91576 Jan 23  2014 ttf2tfm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      101784 Jan 23  2014 ttfdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10544 Mar 16 19:28 ttfread
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       27200 Jan 14 09:20 tty
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         269 Jan  8  2014 twistd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          70 Feb 20  2014 typeoutfileinfo -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/typeoutfileinfo/typeoutfileinfo.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       13240 Feb 25 22:23 tzselect
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Apr 16 19:46 ubuntu-bug -> apport-bug
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        5278 Sep  4  2014 ubuntu-drivers
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        7166 Apr 29  2014 ubuntu-support-status
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18960 Apr  9  2014 ubuntu-webapps-update-index
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       38832 Jul  1  2013 ucf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       19367 Jul  1  2013 ucfq
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10458 Jul  1  2013 ucfr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       17776 Jan  6  2014 ucs2any
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       48368 Mar 10  2014 udisksctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Jun  3  2014 uic -> qtchooser
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Jun  3  2014 uic3 -> qtchooser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14584 Jun  4  2013 ul
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      175640 May 10  2014 umax_pp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       45653 Mar 13 00:48 unattended-upgrade
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          18 Mar 13 00:48 unattended-upgrades -> unattended-upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       31368 Jan 14 09:20 unexpand
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         530 Feb 18  2013 unicode_stop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       39584 Jan 14 09:20 uniq
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        8491 Mar 16 23:14 unity
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       65960 Sep 22  2014 unity-control-center
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10504 Feb 10  2014 unity-scope-loader
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          50 Mar 19 23:39 unity-settings-daemon -> ../lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       40016 Apr  9  2014 unity-webapps-desktop-file
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       27488 Apr  8  2014 unity-webapps-qml-launcher
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       19400 Apr  9  2014 unity-webapps-runner
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       27200 Jan 14 09:20 unlink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          24 Jun  3  2014 unlzma -> /etc/alternatives/unlzma
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root          52 Dec  5  2014 unopkg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          23 Jun 12  2014 unrar -> /etc/alternatives/unrar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      262192 Oct 23  2013 unrar-nonfree
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10432 Feb 13 00:23 unshare
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        5940 Nov  5  2013 unwrapdiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           2 Jun  3  2014 unxz -> xz
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root      158392 Feb 18 01:03 unzip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       76392 Feb 18 01:03 unzipsfx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      111208 Jan 23  2014 upbibtex
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43544 Apr  9 21:21 update-alternatives
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          26 Jun  3  2014 updatedb -> /etc/alternatives/updatedb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43776 Jun 20  2013 updatedb.mlocate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       19088 Nov  5  2013 update-desktop-database
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        5602 Mar 27  2014 update-gconf-defaults
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        4569 Apr 29  2014 update-manager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         672 Apr 11  2014 update-mime-database
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       48192 Apr 11  2014 update-mime-database.real
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       57704 Oct  7  2014 update-notifier
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          53 Feb 17  2014 updmap -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/updmap.pl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          57 Feb 17  2014 updmap-sys -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/updmap-sys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       53768 Jan 23  2014 updvitype
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14752 Dec 22  2013 upower
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       61928 Jan 23  2014 uppltotf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      367112 Jan 23  2014 uptex
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       49608 Jan 23  2014 uptftopl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10512 Feb 11 01:38 uptime
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        3923 Apr 23 16:53 usb-creator-gtk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        4216 Apr  9  2014 usb-devices
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       23064 Apr  9  2014 usbhid-dump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        6344 Feb 19  2014 usb_printerid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       31360 Jan 14 09:20 users
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10432 Feb 13 00:23 uuidgen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        3674 Oct 29  2013 uxterm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        2496 Oct 10  2013 uz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         528 Dec 16  2013 valgrind
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18704 Apr 11  2014 valgrind.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       26944 Apr 11  2014 valgrind-di-server
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10480 Apr 11  2014 valgrind-listener
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 vboxballoonctrl -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 VBoxBalloonCtrl -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 vboxheadless -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 VBoxHeadless -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 vboxmanage -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 VBoxManage -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 vboxsdl -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 VBoxSDL -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 vboxwebsrv -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       51640 Jan 23  2014 vftovp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43576 Apr 11  2014 vgdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          20 Jun  3  2014 vi -> /etc/alternatives/vi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          22 Jun  3  2014 view -> /etc/alternatives/view
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       23856 Aug 16  2013 viewres
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          21 Jun  3  2014 vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          25 Jun  3  2014 vimdiff -> /etc/alternatives/vimdiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2580984 Jan  3  2014 vim.gnome
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      884360 Jan  3  2014 vim.tiny
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        2084 Jan  3  2014 vimtutor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10528 Nov 18  2013 vino-passwd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       31840 Nov 18  2013 vino-preferences
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      510168 Sep 24  2013 virt_mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 virtualbox -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Mar  5 05:37 VirtualBox -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    12103400 Sep 24  2013 virtuoso-t
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14728 Mar 26 08:15 vlc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10560 Mar 26 08:15 vlc-wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14656 Jan 23  2014 vlna
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       31120 Feb 11 01:38 vmstat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10576 Apr 10  2014 vmwarectrl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10240 Feb 25  2014 volname
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          52 Feb 20  2014 vpl2ovp -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/accfonts/vpl2ovp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          52 Feb 20  2014 vpl2vpl -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/accfonts/vpl2vpl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       59776 Jan 23  2014 vptovf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18896 Apr  1  2014 vstp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          19 Jun  3  2014 w -> /etc/alternatives/w
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty        19024 Feb 13 00:23 wall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       23632 Feb 11 01:38 watch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       53272 Feb 23 21:27 wbinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10288 Feb  7  2013 wbmptopbm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       39648 Jan 14 09:20 wc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       67968 Jan 23  2014 weave
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         614 Mar 23  2014 web2disk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       75944 Apr 28  2014 webapp-container
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      231592 Apr 28  2014 webbrowser-app
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         286 Jul  1  2014 wftopfa
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      407696 Oct 30  2014 wget
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       48112 Sep 23  2014 whatis
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       15128 Feb 13 00:23 whereis
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Jun  3  2014 which -> /bin/which
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       51968 Jan 14 09:20 who
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       27200 Jan 14 09:20 whoami
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       52888 Jun 11  2014 whoopsie
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18976 Apr 10  2014 whoopsie-preferences
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      397808 Apr  5  2014 widl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        9748 Apr  5  2014 wine
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1059064 Apr  5  2014 wine64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2110248 Apr  5  2014 wine64-preloader
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           4 Apr  5  2014 wine-auto -> wine
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1582 Apr  5  2014 wineboot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      113248 Apr  5  2014 winebuild
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1582 Apr  5  2014 winecfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1582 Apr  5  2014 wineconsole
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Apr  5  2014 winecpp -> winegcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1582 Apr  5  2014 winedbg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      158624 Apr  5  2014 winedump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1582 Apr  5  2014 winefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      437656 Sep 18  2012 winefish
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Apr  5  2014 wineg++ -> winegcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35280 Apr  5  2014 winegcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       95002 Apr  5  2014 winemaker
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1582 Apr  5  2014 winemine
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1582 Apr  5  2014 winepath
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       12860 Apr  5  2014 wine-preloader
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      425560 Apr  5  2014 wineserver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      640757 Mar  3  2014 winetricks
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18656 Feb  7  2013 winicontoppm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Jun  3  2014 wish -> wish8.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        6192 Mar 13  2014 wish8.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       59944 Apr  5  2014 wmc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      397848 Oct  1  2012 wodim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10376 Dec 15  2013 word-list-compress
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      133504 Jan 23  2014 wovp2ovf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       48056 Apr 20 23:45 wpa_passphrase
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18872 Feb 11 01:38 w.procps
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      221808 Apr  5  2014 wrc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43896 Feb 19  2014 wrestool
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          23 Jun  3  2014 write -> /etc/alternatives/write
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          27 Jun  3  2014 wx-config -> /etc/alternatives/wx-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      101824 Dec  2  2013 wxrc
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root       10192 Dec 10  2014 X
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           1 Jun  3  2014 X11 -> .
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      138104 Jan  6  2014 x11perf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        2807 Jan  6  2014 x11perfcomp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Feb 13 00:23 x86_64 -> setarch
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-addr2line -> addr2line
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           2 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-ar -> ar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           2 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-as -> as
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-c++filt -> c++filt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp -> cpp-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp-4.8 -> cpp-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           3 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-dwp -> dwp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-elfedit -> elfedit
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Apr  8  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -> g++-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Apr  5  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-4.8 -> g++-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> gcc-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8 -> gcc-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-4.8 -> gcc-ar-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-4.8 -> gcc-nm-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          14 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          14 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-4.8 -> gcc-ranlib-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcov -> gcov-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Jun  3  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcov-4.8 -> gcov-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-gprof -> gprof
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           2 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -> ld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           6 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd -> ld.bfd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.gold -> ld.gold
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           2 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-nm -> nm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-objcopy -> objcopy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-objdump -> objdump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           6 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib -> ranlib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-readelf -> readelf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           4 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-size -> size
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-strings -> strings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Feb  9 17:06 x86_64-linux-gnu-strip -> strip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43624 Jan  6  2014 xargs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       40304 Dec  4  2012 xauth
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       17296 Jan  6  2014 xbiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10336 Feb  7  2013 xbmtopbm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       32848 Jan  6  2014 xcalc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       55376 Mar 12  2014 xcf2png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       55376 Mar 12  2014 xcf2pnm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       22608 Mar 12  2014 xcfinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        1696 Mar 12  2014 xcfview
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       23056 Feb 19  2014 xclip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       17120 Jan  6  2014 xclipboard
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         572 Feb 19  2014 xclip-copyfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         386 Feb 19  2014 xclip-cutfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         133 Feb 19  2014 xclip-pastefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       43312 Jan  6  2014 xclock
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       31728 Feb 18  2014 xcmsdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       16512 Jan  6  2014 xconsole
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       12648 Jan  6  2014 xcursorgen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       11408 Jan  6  2014 xcutsel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       15559 Jul 18  2014 xdg-desktop-icon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       38175 Jul 18  2014 xdg-desktop-menu
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       21469 Jul 18  2014 xdg-email
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       24667 Jul 18  2014 xdg-icon-resource
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       34208 Jul 18  2014 xdg-mime
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       13794 Jul 18  2014 xdg-open
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       25432 Jul 18  2014 xdg-screensaver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       25565 Jul 18  2014 xdg-settings
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         234 Apr 11  2014 xdg-user-dir
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       19200 Jul  3  2013 xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18864 Apr 11  2014 xdg-user-dirs-update
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        4597 Mar 23  2014 xdiagnose
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       88368 Jan  6  2014 xditview
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       32208 Aug 16  2013 xdpyinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10376 Aug 16  2013 xdriinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        3031 Jan 23  2014 xdvi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          26 Jun  3  2014 xdvi.bin -> /etc/alternatives/xdvi.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      631000 Jan 23  2014 xdvipdfmx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      623632 Jan 23  2014 xdvi-xaw
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        7312 Mar 23  2014 xedid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      621544 Jan  6  2014 xedit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      665736 Jan 23  2014 xetex
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       27304 Aug 16  2013 xev
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       20944 Jan  6  2014 xeyes
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       28936 Aug 16  2013 xfd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       37184 Aug 16  2013 xfontsel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        6936 Jan  6  2014 xfsinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       10432 Feb 18  2014 xgamma
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       61192 Jan  6  2014 xgc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      263304 Apr 28  2014 xgettext
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       14728 Feb 18  2014 xhost
```

Comment: Please add the result of the command `ls -l /usr/bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a problem!! let me explain.

If you run the command:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/X11

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1 Apr  8  2014 /usr/bin/X11 -> .
```

As you see above this directory is in deed just a symlink  to  the current directory which is `/usr/bin`. So whenever you navigate into this dir you'll remain in same place so you think it's not opening.

#### But Why Ubuntu use such thing?

Some apps expect some other apps inside the dir /usr/bin/X11 so for that ubuntu just keep them inside the /usr/bin and make symlink of /usr/bin/X11 to /usr/bin

#### Answering your comments

Java installation in deed is not inside `/usr/bin`, infact it's under `/usr/lib/jvm/...`

Now `if you run` whereis java`it gives`/usr/bin/java`, this doesn't mean that java installation is in /usr/bin, this indicates that only binary is in /usr/bin.

`man whereis`

```
NAME
       whereis  -  locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a com‐
       mand
```

And In really either the binary inside /usr/bin is just a symlink to the original binary in /usr/lib/jvm.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Apr 10  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

This indicates that /usr/bin/java is symlink to /etc/alternatives/java, now let's check what is /etc/alternatives/java.

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java 

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Apr 10  2014 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

And here we go, that file is really also a symlink to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java as we say before.

Comment: I've opened this machine after a long time and I have installed java in /usr/bin/java/....
I wanted t go into that folder and see what all files are there. What should I do ?
I was actually looking for the jdk location

Comment: run the command  `ls /usr/bin` you can see all files there, you al ready did it in the edit of your answer

Comment: but I want to open the /usr/bin/java directory

Comment: There is no directory /usr/bin/java. Indeed java will be under /usr/lib/jvm

Comment: Hmm. ok

whereis java

gives me the output :
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/local/java /usr/share/java

Hence I figured java is in bin.
However I found my jdk in the usr/local/java directory.

Thanks for helping :-)

Comment: I'll edit my answer and explain that to you

Comment: @UmangMathur Check the edit

Comment: Thank you. I guess the problem was in my faulty understanding of how the "whereis" command works.

Comment: Always try the `ls -l` it shows you some more info about files